# html 5 style="background-color: yellow;" or style="background-color: #FF0000;" does not chnage the color of table row

Tags: css, html, jsp

In a jsp page based on row value (true/false) condition I am trying to change the color of row. Here when value is true row has no color but when false then yellow color. I am getting true or false value of the table but the color doesn't change

```
     <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${Cvalue == true}">
                <tr>
                    <td class="firstColumn"><c:out
                            value="${Cvalue}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <tr style="background-color: yellow;" >
                    <td class="firstColumn"><c:out
                            value="${Cvalue}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

Comment: your tr is not close in the otherwise clause

Comment: Maybe try to indent your rows differently. You probably would have noticed the missing </tr> if you did.

Comment: sorry that </tr> was just a typo here. I will add that in the question

Comment: is is possible to provide a fiddle

Comment: @MHHasnain I am unable to replecate it in fiddle